# Get list of classes from an inherited module programmatically

Tags: gwt

How do I get the list of classes from an inherited module programmatically?
Let's say I inherit from module com.example.Example, how can I get the classes involved with the module?

Comment: In which moment do you want to know that classes? compiler time? in server side runtime? client side production mode?

Comment: I don't get client side production mode. What is it please? Anyway, what I want to know is if I can print the classes.

Comment: client side means javascript. I guess you want to know them in compile time or as a independent tool you can run anytime, added my response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GWT, at run-time, you can't really. When the GWT compiles from your java files into javascript, it obtusifies all the names of methods and variables. The names literally don't exist at run-time.

You would have to create something that runs at compile time, like a generator, that processes a directory when you compile your code. You can google how to do it, but you might want to rethink why you need the class listing, or see if you can move that functionality on to your server side.

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool for doing that except setting log level to TRACE during compile time and see all modules being visited.

You can use as reference [this 'GraphDependencies tool'](https://gwt-review.googlesource.com/#/c/1210/2/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/tools/GraphDependencies.java) written by Thomas Broyer some time ago and which is pending to review.

You can use the `ResourceOracleImpl` for getting all resources calling the `oracle.getResources()` or the `oracle.getResourceMap()` which groups resources, instead of the `oracle.getPathNames()` utilised in this class.

Comment: I had a hard time selecting the answer. The one by @BenRitter is a good one because I was opened to the option of creating a generator. Your answer on the other hand seems plausible also, +1. Thanks.

Comment: IIRC the problem using generators is that in the oracle you might not have info about modules, although you have a list with all the classes loaded, so probably you could not know what classes belongs to a module unless you inspect the namespace which is not accurate.